# Flexbox form width does not change

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get a form's inputs to fill the container width but since I am using two flexboxes, it doesn't seem to allow me to set the width of the input boxes. Is there a way around this? I've tried using `flex-shrink` but got the same result.

What is the best way to set a form's width to fill its container using flexbox?

```css
.sd-form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.sd-form-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.sd-form-group input[type=text],
.sd-form-group textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="sd-form-group">
    <div class="sd-form-wrap">
      <div class="form-name form-first-name">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-name form-last-name">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-email">
      <label>Email</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-message">
      <label>Message</label>
      <br>
      <textarea placeholder="Enter your comments, questions and feedback here." rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>
        Communications box
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the container, instead of `flex-flow: column nowrap` use `row wrap`.

On the items, force each one to occupy the full width of the row.

```css
.sd-form-group {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-flow: column nowrap; */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* new */
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-items: flex-start; */ /* does nothing */
}

.sd-form-group > div {
  flex: 0 0 100%; /* new */
}

.sd-form-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.sd-form-group input[type=text],
.sd-form-group textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="sd-form-group">
    <div class="sd-form-wrap">
      <div class="form-name form-first-name">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="form-name form-last-name">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-email">
      <label>Email</label>
      <br>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-message">
      <label>Message</label>
      <br>
      <textarea placeholder="Enter your comments, questions and feedback here." rows="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <label>
        Communications box
      </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I need the `flex-flow` to be `nowrap` for something else I am doing. Is there a way to work around that or does it overcomplicate it?

Comment: Well, the overcomplication would depend on what else you're doing. My answer attempts to keep it simple. Alternatively, I guess you could apply widths to all the elements to force them to consume space.

Comment: Hi Michael, can you please review this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67190156/why-adding-overflow-control-to-inner-div-is-breaking-outer-container-flex-flow .. a perfect duplicate reopened by non-CSS users (or maybe it's not and you can either give a better duplicate or an answer)

Comment: @TemaniAfif, Yes. Agreed. A duplicate. Alas, the question was deleted, so it's a moot point. Sorry for the delayed response. Best regards...